# QT designer with C++ about connect

Tags: qt

I want to know if it is possible to connect a QUI created with QT with another program, like HSPICE that simulates electronics. I want to have a slot that you put a number (capacitance of a capasitor) and that number by clicking an action button to became input to the HSPICE program and execute it with that input.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Qt GUI around any functionality that you want. Whether your gui widgets trigger code that is completely yours, or calls out via a pipe to an external application is up to you. You could write an app that is just gui logic and completely controls something remote over a network socket even.

The GUI simply wraps around system commands that can call your external binary.

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if it addressed your question. Thx!